# How to show images like the way of iPhone native photo album (4 images in a row)?

Tags: ios, image, camera

I want to take some pictures with the iPhone camera and show them like a wall (4 images in a row). And then I can select some of them to use. Anyone help ? Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

You can have custom buttons instead of `uiimageviews`
You can add the images in the button from camera using this code.

```
- (void)selectPhotos
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    picker.delegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
        didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image
                  editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    [button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

And then in the selector method you can retrive the image from the button like this

```
button.imageView.image
```

Comment: Using button is an interesting way! I will try. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

or...you can just use UIImageViews as

```
-(void)DrawImageViews:(UIImage*)fImage{

float start_X=2.0;
float start_Y_image=2.0;

for(int idx=0;idx<12;idx++)
{
    UIImageView *imageView = [ [ UIImageView alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(start_X, start_Y_image, 78, HEIGHT)];
    imageView.image=fImage;

    [self addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];

    if((idx+1)%4==0 && idx!=0) {
        start_X=2.0;
        start_Y_image += HEIGHT+2;
    }
    else
        start_X += 78 + 2;
    }}
```

here I've drawn the same image 12 times and kept a padding of 2 on both sides. Then, you can find which row and column was tapped using delegate method:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
UITouch *touch =[touches anyObject];
CGPoint currentPoint =[touch locationInView:self];

NSInteger column = ((NSInteger)((currentPoint.x)/80) + 1);
NSInteger row = ((NSInteger)((currentPoint.y)/(HEIGHT + 2) + 1);}
```

I've locally declared row and column here. you'll have to make accessible from outside!